# Rails help ActionView::Template::Error HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, heroku

My rails app runs fine on my locale machine with mysql.
But on Heroku I get the following error: http://pastie.org/1697772

My kategoris_helper:

```
module KategorisHelper
def sortkat(column, title = nil)
  title ||= column.titleize
  css_class = column == sort_column ? "current #{sort_direction}" : nil
  direction = column == sort_column && sort_direction == "asc" ? "desc" : "asc"
  link_to title, {:sort => column, :direction => direction}, {:class => css_class}
end
end
```

My Kategoris controller:

```
class KategorisController < ApplicationController
    @kategori = Kategori.find(:first, :conditions => "cached_slug = '#{params[:id]}'")
    @konkurrencer = @kategori.konkurrancers.order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction)
    @titel = @kategori.name
  end

private

def sort_column
  Konkurrancer.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : "created_at"
end

  def sort_direction
    %w[desc asc].include?(params[:direction]) ? params[:direction] : "desc"
  end
end
```

My models:

```
class Kategori < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :konkurrancers
    has_friendly_id :name, :use_slug => true
end

class Konkurrancer < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :kategori
    has_friendly_id :name, :use_slug => true
end
```

Comment: `<%= sortkat "udtraekkes", "Udtr+ªkkes" %></td>` do you actually have that or is the log messing things up?

Comment: I have <%= sortkat "udtraekkes", "Udtrækkes" %> in my view file

Comment: It might be a character encoding issue, but it could also have something to do with your templates. Which ruby/rails are you using. Post your helpers and view templates so we an check the code

Comment: I am using rails 3.0.3 and Ruby 1.9.2p136

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PostgreSQL is unforgiving my kategori_id was varchar.

Changed it to be an integer. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem:

```
  css_class = column == sort_column ? "current #{sort_direction}" : nil
  direction = column == sort_column && sort_direction == "asc" ? "desc" : "asc
```

I'm not quite sure what your doing here but I think the error is coming from you using `=` and `==` on the same line. Your setting a variable that is comparing itself to another variable.

You ned to change it so you don't have == in there.

Comment: Then I get following error http://pastie.org/1697889 both on my locale pc and on heroku

Comment: What is the status? Can you tell me what your trying to do?

Comment: I think there is something wrong with the action:     @kategori = Kategori.find(:first, :conditions => "cached_slug = '#{params[:id]}'")
    @konkurrancer = (@kategori.konkurrancers).order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction)

Comment: Becuse @konkurrancer = Konkurrancer.order((sort_column + " " + sort_direction)) works on heroku

Comment: quite honestly I don't know what your doing. If you tell me what you want then I can write the code for you ;)

Comment: I am quite sure it is the action/finder method that is wrong. My action works with MySQL but not with herokus PostgreSQL. The action should find all konkurrancer that belongs to the kategori.

Comment: ok cool, Yeah it could also be a ruby version issue. I have similar problem to you my friend. Good luck :)

Comment: Have you found a solution for your problem?

Comment: no I'm really sorry. You just have some custom code and I don't know what it's doing so it hard to say.

Comment: I want to display all konkurrancers that belons to the given kategori. The params are the cached_slug of the kategori. Is it clear what I am trying to do. I have also updated the post with my models. :)

Comment: Probably should have thought about this earlier. Can you use gem 'mysql' instead of postgress. Just declare it in your bundler file.

Comment: Yes I have gem 'mysql', '2.8.1' and can use it. Heroku usage PostgreSQL