# Rails help rewriting show action to PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

How do I write this to something PostgreSQL understands?

```
  def show
    @kategori = Kategori.find(:first, :conditions => "cached_slug = '#{params[:id]}'")
    @konkurrancer = (@kategori.konkurrancers).order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction)
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper Rails3 syntax for this would be

```
def show
  @kategori = Kategori.where(:cached_slug => params[:id]).first
  @konkurrancer = @kategori.konkurrancers.order("#{sort_column} #{sort_direction}")
end
```

Comment: Still get the error: HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: You need to give us more info than that. Give us the entire error and line number, etc. Possibly model definitions as well.

Comment: Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384982/rails-help-actionviewtemplateerror-hint-no-operator-matches-the-given-name

Comment: This not a postgres error. It's an error in your programming logic. You need to debug the actual Ruby code to see what it is passing to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Good stuff! breaking it into chunks.

```
def show
 @kategori = Kategori.find(:first, :conditions => ['cached_slug=?', params[:id]])
end
```

I'm not sure about the other column, looks fine through.

Comment: Still get the error:  HINT:  No operator matches the given name
and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: Then that has something to do with the second line.

Comment: Have you checked that the params[:id] is actually providing a number, not a blank space? Maybe wrap the find statement inside an if params[:id] != nil && !params[:id].empty?..else clause. Could also try casting the params[:id] to an integer just to make sure (params[:id].to_i).

Comment: The strange thing it works on my locale pc. But on heroku it gives a error. Do you now how to active view error messages in heroku?

Comment: The params(id) is a cached slug (varchar)